# Antivirus blocking Ajax sync requests

Tags: ajax, synchronous, antivirus

Out of a sudden I realized that the Ajax requests that I make synchronously work no more and the only thing left for me is to close the browser tab as it hangs forever. The problem is not with a particular request but with all synchronous Ajax requests in my web application. If I turn them to `async:true`, then the problem gets solved. After some digging I found out that Kaspersky antivirus was blocking them. All the computers that I test the application on use Kaspersky for "virus-fighting" purposes. I tried with all major browsers and all present the same problem. Now a few things to note:

1. I didn't use to have this problem just a couple hours ago.
2. The application server also has Kaspersky running but AJAX sync request work normally(which makes me come to a conclusion that the problem is with the response)
3. I've put another simple test application  with AJAX sync request and they work normally
4. Other antivirus programs don't cause such a problem.

So do you have any ideas what the problem might be? Is it something that I need to ask in Kaspersky forum?